# Why can't an embedding have self-intersections?

Tags: general-topology, derivatives, differential-geometry, injective-module, continuous-homomorphisms

If I understood it correctly an embedding is an immersion $\phi:M \rightarrow N$ that is a homeomorphism and where $\phi (M) \subset N$.
To which condition contradicts an immersion with a self-intersection?
(An example is $\phi(t)=(t^3-4t,t^2-4)$)

Comment: Homeomorphism to its image! Homeomorphisms are, in particular, bijections.

Comment: If the image $\phi(M)$ has a self-intersection, then the map $\phi$ is not injective, hence is not bijective, hence is not a homeomorphism onto its image.